# Comparison of a set of strings and a file using Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am trying to write a Perl script which will find out the difference between a set of strings and a file, and I want to print the contents of the file which doesnt match the strings.

My INPUT1 will be like :(Set of strings)

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
EEEEE   --- These are user ids which should be passed in the script
```

My INPUT2 will be a file as User.txt which has numerous id including those mentioned above

```
ABBAAA
ACARVAV
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
EEEEE
BGATA
ETYUIOL
```

I want my ouput to be like

```
ABBAAA
ACARVAV
BGATA
ETYUIOL
```

So far I have arrived at

```
my @things_to_find = qw(AAAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE);
my $comparefile = "User.txt";
open ( my $compare_filehandle, "<", $comparefile ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$compare_filehandle> ) 
{
    foreach my $thing ( @things_to_find )
    {
        print "Match found with: $line" if $line !~ /$thing/;
    }
}
```

But this is not producing the desired output. I am very new to Perl, so any suggestions from you will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with:

```
use List::Util qw(none);
my @things_to_find = qw(AAAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE);
my $comparefile = "User.txt";
open ( my $compare_filehandle, "<", $comparefile ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$compare_filehandle> ) 
{
    print $line if none { $line =~ /\b$_\b/}  @things_to_find;
}
```

Doc [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)

Comment: What if the file had `BBBBBC` in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple `grep` for matched pattern.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @users = qw(AAAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE);

my $file = "User.txt";
open my $fh, "<", $file;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    print "Matched line : $line\n" unless grep {$line eq $_} @users;
}
```

**Note:**
For searching pattern use  `grep` and `map` better  than  `foreach` or `for` .

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your own code finds all the lines in the file that *don't contain all* of the strings in the list when it should be *don't equal any* of those strings. You need to change the containment test to an equality test; skip the string as soon as a match is found; and use `chomp` to remove the trailing newline from the strings read from the file.

There are two obvious ways to write this. The first is to build a *hash*, which is effectively an array that is indexed by a string instead of an integer. If you fill the hash with entries from the file and then delete those that are in the array of strings. That would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $comparefile = 'User.txt';
my @users = qw/ AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE /;

open my $users_fh, '<', $comparefile or die $!;

my %file_users;
while (my $user = <$users_fh> ) {
  chomp $user;
  $file_users{$user} = 1;
}

delete $file_users{$_} for @users;

print "$_\n" for sort keys %file_users;
```

**output**

```
ABBAAA
ACARVAV
BGATA
ETYUIOL
```

The other way is to build a *regular expression* from the strings, and use it to select those lines from the file that are to be ignored. That would look like the program below, and the output is identical to that of the previous program. This solution will be faster, but includes some more advanced ideas like regular expressions and `map` so you may prefer the first.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $comparefile = 'User.txt';
my @users = qw/ AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE /;

my $re = join '|', map "^\Q$_\E\$", @users;
$re = qr/$re/;

open my $users_fh, '<', $comparefile or die $!;

my @file_users;
while (my $user = <$users_fh> ) {
  chomp $user;
  push @file_users, $user unless $user =~ $re;
}

print "$_\n" for sort @file_users;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt'; 
open my $in2, '<', 'in_2.txt';

my (%data1, %data2);
while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    $data1{$_} = 1;
}

while(<$in2>){
    chomp;
    $data2{$_} = 2;
}


foreach(sort keys %data2){
    print "$_\n" unless $data1{$_};
}
```